# adding an element to binary search tree

Tags: python, algorithm, search, tree, binary

Hi my question is how can i fix the code for my add function for my binary search tree program.

```
class BTNode2:
    def __init__(self,d,l,r):
        self.data = d
        self.left = l
        self.right = r
        self.mult = 1
```

And this is the add method

```
def add(self, d):   
    if (self < d.data):
        if (d.left != None):
            add(self, d.left)
        else:
            d.left = BTNode2(self)
    else:
        if (d.right != None):
            add(self, d.right)
        else:
            d.right = BTNode2(self)
    return
```

This is the error i get when i try to run the add method:

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'data'

Comment: Hold on, it seems that you have implmented in the opposite way, here your `self` seems to be the item you want to add, and the `d` the tree?

Comment: yes thats correct

Comment: but since you define this method on the `BTNode2` class, `self` is always the callee, so the `BTNode2` object here where you wist to add an extra value to.

Answer (score 1):

In essence, you swapped the parameters of the `add` function, since `self` is the tree here, and `d` the data element to add. Furthermore in order to construct such `BTNode2`s with only one parameter, you should add a default value for `l` and `r`. Finally depending on what `mult` does, you might want to change this in the add algorithm, but it is not really clear what it represents.

So we can fix this to:

```
class BTNode2:
    def __init__(self, d, l=None, r=None):
        self.data = d
        self.left = l
        self.right = r
        self.mult = 1

    def add(self, d):   
        if d < self.data:
            if self.left is not None:
                self.left.add(d)
            else:
                self.left = BTNode2(d)
        else:
            if self.right is not None:
                self.right.add(d)
            else:
                self.right = BTNode2(d)
```